# Bug Conexión en Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al realizar una conexión en sql developer y realizar insert en cualquier tabla de la base de esa conexión, en mi instancia si se presentan los datos actualizado.
Pero al realizar otra conexión a la misma base no se refleja los datos insertados.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sabes que es un commit??? porque te esta faltando eso.. no hay ningun bug....

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, realmente era algo obvio.